# Difference in "edited posts" in editor stats and user profile

Tags: bug, editing, suggested-edits

I noticed that there is an inconsistency in the number of edited posts between the "editor stats" (which is the dialog that you can see in post revisions) and the user profile. For example, according to the editor stats, I have had 102 edit suggestions approved:

[image]

while on my user profile, the number of edited posts is 61:

[image]

which is also in accordance with the progress on the "Strunk & White" badge (edit 80 posts).

So which of these numbers is correct? I had two ideas to explain the difference, the first being that the editor stats are network-wide (for all stack exchange sites) while the number on the user profile is only for Physics SE. However, a quick check showed that the editor stats show different numbers on different sites (the same is true for the user profile).

The other idea was that the editor stats include the number of my own posts that I edited. This could technically be true since the difference does not exceed the number of my posts, but edits on your own posts do not have to be approved (which is suggested by the editor stats) - if anything, edits on own posts *could* be included on the user profile which does not specify that the edits were "approved". However, this obviously would make no sense since the number is smaller.

So why is there a difference and which is the "true" (i.e. edited posts of other users) number?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three possibilities, of which the first one is to blame for the majority of the difference.

- The "102 edit suggestions approved" counts edits on deleted posts, while the "61 posts edited" does not. [This SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/1379127/approved-suggested-edits-on-deleted-posts?UserId=253179) lists 28 such instances, which is not enough to explain the entire difference.

  - As noted in the comments, SEDE updates once a week, on Sunday morning, so your most recent edits don't appear there yet. But they're not likely to be on deleted posts; [Roomba](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) only works on posts older than a week.
- If you suggest an edit to a post twice, and both get approved, the number of edit suggestions approved increases, but the number of posts edited does not.
- The 61 posts edited counts edits to community wikis as well; those don't need to be approved.

Comment: Friendly reminder that the SEDE is a static cache which updates only weekly. The [youngest post in the Physics SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/1351093/newest-post-in-sede#resultSets) is currently dated 2021-02-21 04:07:52, so the "missing 12" edits probably were made this week. You'll get better agreement if you update this answer tomorrow :-)

Comment: @rob thanks, that explains the difference.